# Plotting data in for loop

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I'm having issues plotting data while using a `for` loop. My function, as it stands, looks like this:

```
function fig = Function1(input1,input2,input3)
fig = figure('Visable',false);
%% Load in all files from 3 different folders (input1,input2,input3)
%% Initiate for loop and process data on each file iteration. After data is processed, plot results from that iteration and hold on to the plot for the next iteration.
for i = 1 : length(Text_Files1)
    % Read in data as tables
    % Process data (Cropping data ect)
    % Pass through function to calculate heart rates  
    [~,HR,~] = HrFunction(data1, ...
        data2);
    
    % Calculate average heart rate over segments. (xTime is a datetime array)    
    hrT = seconds(xTime - startTime);
    TrendWindow = 900;    
    TimeSegment = 1:TrendWindow:max(hrT);    

    % Iterate through each time segment and calculate average heart rate    
    for x = 1:length(TimeSegment)-1        
        SegmentScores = find(hrT > TimeSegment(x) & ...
            hrT < TimeSegment(x+1));        
        hrTre(x) = mean(HR(SegmentScores));        
        hrTime(x) = TimeSegment(x+1); % in seconds        
    end
    
    %% Plot hrTre from each iteration on the same figure
    hold on
    plot(hrTime, hrTre);
end
end
```

The plot I am getting looks like it has the exact same shape on each iteration and some iterations are plotted on top of each other, (IE, have the same `xTime` values which shouldn't happen). Where I am going wrong?

Comment: The for-loop you describe iterates over a time segment (a 1D signal) and for each scalar value of `x` puts 1 value in the (1D) vector `hrTre`. If you want `hrTre` to be a 2D variable, you need to assign `hrTre(:,x) = ...` -- except that I'm not sure what `...` should be, because it looks like `mean(HR(SegmentScores))` is a single scalar (if you did not get any errors or warnings).

Comment: Both hrTre and hrTime should be 1D variables, both will be Nx1 arrays. N changing with each iteration